# Piwik is breaking title if #-symbol is used

Tags: php, matomo

Piwik do not track the Page Title in Outgoing References correctly if iam using a #-symbol in the page title. The url encoding in the piwik request is correctly. But piwik proceed the encoded %23 (#) incorrect.

piwik.php?link=http%3A%2F%2F_mediathek%2FStartseite%2FNews%20Center%2FBranchen%20News%2F  %23   Video%20zuerst%2FVideo%20in%20einer%20Nerws&idsite=...

Everything that comes after the # is cut off (in the title).

iam Using a old piwik version 1.11.1. How can i fix this issue? For me, at the moment it is not possible to change to a another piwik version.

Comment: The # needs URL encoded otherwise the browser will assume it's the "fragment" part of the URL and not send it. I'm not sure what you mean by the # was processed incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, i know. And it is URL encoded in the Requested URL. But Piwik Core cant interpret the encoded symbol corretly. %23 (#) Example: piwik.php?link=http%3A%2F%2F_test%2F%23Test -> piwik.php?link=http://_test/#Test

Comment: We're not Piwik support, without more information and the relevant code there's nothing we can do or say.